# Draw square around certain pixels on screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, drawrectangle

**EDITED as per request to refine:**

I'm using CV2 to compare two screen shots with a specified time delay between refreshing the two screenshots. If there's a difference between the two images (by subtracting them) I get the pixel coordinates that are different.

[ScriptRunning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QPkm.png)

**What I want to do now** is draw box(or highlight) around where those differences(found pixel coordinates) on the screen are in real time. **Not in an image.** Like a surveillance camera shows a green box around motion in camera footage, I want to do that but on the users screen.

The reason I did the images comparison and refreshing loop in python3 because I know how to do it in python and no other language. I've tried drawing a rectangle using turtle, but that opens a new "turtle window" and draws a box. I want it to highlight whats on the screen in a non-intrusive way. So far, thats the only thing I've tried as I don't really know where to go from here.

**EDIT:**

Here's what my current script looks like:

```
pastebin.com/cYmDNZfv
```

Comment: Does your question boil down to "How do I draw rectangles on screen using Python, or maybe not Python?" It would be helpful if you highlighted exactly what you're trying to achieve, and removed everything else (such as any extraneous discussion about screen grabs and long example list of coordinates).

Comment: Fair enough. I just want to check if anything on the screen has changed within x (seconds). If so, draw rectangle around the parts that changed. Imagine you're looking at document or page or app that has a bunch of dynamic text in it and say one or more words changes on the page you're on. I want to draw a box around the word(s) that changed. I chose python because I'm most comfortable with it is all. And chose images to compare because it might not always be text that changes etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to highlight specifically what you need. Sounds like you've already figured out how to take a diff of two screenshots. So remove all of that, and anything else you don't need help with. Then expand on what it is you're missing, and what attempt you have made. Not in a comment, but by editing your question.

Comment: Are the original images displayed in a non-python window? I'm not sure how you could interact with that. If on the other hand they are displayed through a python based window like TKinter or PyQt window then there should be a way.

Comment: Hey Robb, I'm not displaying the screenshots at all to the end user. I'm storing them in variables and doing the compare on the fly. I'd rather not save the screens at all really in the end. I'm just using them to figure out if anything on the screen has changed within the last second. I can post my code for this if it helps, but it's not "cleaned up" yet..and not sure if its helpful since that part already works.

Answer (score 0):

First use something like below to find the difference , then use OpenCV: Contours to get coordinates of the rectangles so formed!(I have left the contours part for you to do!)

```
import cv2

l1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
l2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg')

diff1 = cv2.absdiff(l2, l1)
diff1 = cv2.cvtColor(diff1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Difference between images', diff1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After using the above code you have to detect all the available contours in the `diff1` image and then use `cv2.rectangle(position,dimensions)` to draw the rectangles around the significant contours!
For info about contours follow: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Comment: thanks I'm looking into it.. I'm reading up on the cv2.rectangle now. Are you sure this can work for what I want, it looks like it only draws rectangles around existing images. I want the rectangle to be around the differences in the images, but NOT on the image itself, but instead around the  coordinates on the screen in real time where the image represented the difference... dont want to see the image at all or block user input with the rectangle....essentially "motion detection" on the screen. kinda like you see in surveillance cameras when theres motion and a green box around it

Comment: The rectangles have to be formed over any image , You can draw them over your `diff1` image or them **captured_image** or over a **blank image** , it's completely upon you to choose which image you want to draw on. After choosing simply use `cv2.rectangle(image_reference_you_chose, pt1, pt2, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]])`

Comment: Sorry , you cannot draw directly on to the screen!

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion. Apps like Snaggit and others use screen drawing. There's gotta be a way to hit Windows API to draw it. Maybe just not in python...

Comment: are you monitoring the desktop through opencv? if yes , you can actually draw on opencv captured frames(frames through mss)!

Comment: I updated my question with what I'm doing to "monitor the screen"

Comment: Sorry i don't know any way of drawing over desktop!

Answer (score 0):

Assume for now that there are three images for a particular comparison run:

- Image 1 represents the original screenshot.
- Image 2 represents the changed/altered screenshot.
- Image 3 represents the (literal) difference between Image 1 and Image 2 when Image 1 is subtracted from Image 2 after both (Image 1 and Image 2) have been converted to greyscale.

Now, here's how I would break the problem down.

STEPS:

1. For one instance, derive Image 3 and not store it. Image 3 should consist of all zeros (or black color) except areas that had changes. You might want to consider converting negative pixel values to positive ones.
2. Run an if-statement check to see if the total of all the pixel values in Image 3 is greater than 0 to check if changes happened.
3. If the total is greater than 0, break Image 3 down into very small blocks/cells (and not pixels). By "break Image 3 down", I mean apply a grid and break into individual square blocks/cells. See code [here](https://github.com/troymyname/damagedetectionanalysis/blob/master/APPLY_grid.py) for help. You can use this code to derive coordinates of those blocks.
4. Once you have the coordinates, run a loop through each one of the blocks to pinpoint exactly where the change(s) happened.
5. Once you know where the change(s) happened and the corresponding coordinates, use the CV2 function [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) to draw rectangle(s) on either Image 1 or Image 2 to show where the change(s) happened.
6. Display the image with the rectangle(s) showing possible change(s).
7. Put steps 1 - 6 in a loop with a time delay before going to the next instance run.

Comment: I have 1-5 working but with pixels. I'll look into your step 3 though if its more accurate thanks. But step 6 isn't what I want. I updated my question to be more clear. I don't want to draw the rectangle onto an image I want to draw it on the users screen so they can see where the display changed

Comment: That's what I thought too. "Drawing" the rectangle doesn't necessarily mean drawing and saving the image. It's just displaying the rectangle on the screen.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Oh yes , which ever answer works for you shall be marked as accepted , So choose and accept by clicking the green tick!

Comment: I don't understand how to "display the rectangle on the screen" without displaying the whole image on the screen. And displaying the whole image on the screen would block the users input. I don't want that. If I wanted to draw three green rectangles around three different words that have changed in a pdf, or three different lines that have changed in the last second and get the user to click on those spots. I just want to highlight what changed in the screen every x seconds.

Comment: I don't think you can point the changes out on top of an actual document while detecting the change in a screenshot inside a Python environment.

Comment: well to simplify leaving the detection side out... if I simply have coordinates on the screen. Position  x,y and I want to draw a box around that. can it be done in python?